# How to "Distribute Rows" in a table in PowerPoint slide using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a table in `PowerPoint` which I need to "Distribute Rows" evenly. Manually, I could go to "layout" and click on the "Distribute Rows" option.

But what is the `VBA` code to do it using a macro?

Thanks!